# how can I make `git` fail instead of asking for credentials

Tags: node.js, git

I am trying to use git commands inside my script, and I want git to fail in any case so that I can check for errors my users supplied in their requests.

The current behavior of `git` is like this:

- the address is not a git repo, it fails.
- user space does not exist, it asks for a username/password
- repo does not exist or is possibly private, it asks for a username/password
- given username/password/token is wrong, it asks for a username/password.

But this is not just a simple "ask for credentials" function executed, but rather git spawns many other processes all with different process IDs, and also for some reason kills the original spawned process without notifying my spawner script. (Node.js' spawn)

At first, I tried using a timeout to kill the main spawned process if it does not write a response to its stdout but since there is no process with that ID anymore, I fail to check further for errors. I had to give up trying to clone a repo unless supplied address can be fetched from a public api.

All my searches ended up on the other side of the coin, "make it to ask for a password". I wonder if I failed to think of correct search terms for my purpose, or if it is just that there is no such way.

Please enlighten me if there is a flag I have missed, or some other way to do the trick.

PS: I hesitated but I have added node.js tag, but this might be a problem in any language that can spawn child processes.

Comment: Reading the text, this sounds like a classic XY problem: the problem isn't the fail state, it's what happens with the `spawn`ed process. So what's the spawn code you're using, and [mcve] code that shows things going wrong, which OS and version of git are you using, and how are you running the script (because depending on your terminal or IDE, that can and will interfere)?

Comment: Keep in mind that Git doesn't do any authentication. So whoever is asking for the credentials is not Git.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it is not about the script, this thing happens when you invoke commands from terminal. by the way, bk2204 's answer does the job.

Comment: @matt git starts the credentials process so it is still git to blame :)
by the way, bk2204 's answer does the job. git does not try to start any credential process, if and only if there is no window manager running.
thanks for the interest

Comment: while it also happens on the terminal, spawn _should be able to deal with this_ if you set the correct stdio and event handling, so you might very well still be solving a symptom, not the problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the problem I had with Nodejs's spawn and git was that git itself spawns many other processes and sometimes for some reason, it kills the original process Node spawned. I was trying to track the child process and kill it after a while but it was not there nor was sending any signal back to Node before died. so I had to give up doing that till now. I have no idea why git kills the original process like that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What is it you are trying to achieve here? this post is not about how to correct my code. and I don't need anything other than on-close and on-exit and PID. maybe I had bugs at the time but that does not give you the right to accuse me like that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I agree with your point but not with your attitude in your previous comment. git spawns a lot of processes along with credential prompting, and it is possible I missed something while I was working. it's been months and I don't even know if those codes are still existing somewhere. yet it does not change the fact that this post is about "making git fail" in such situations I prompted in the body of the post.

Comment: That's fair - no attitude was intended and I'll be happy to remove the comments so it doesn't sidetrack future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid Git prompting for credentials, you can set `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0`.  That will prevent Git itself from prompting using a credential helper or making any other terminal requests, but it will not prevent other tools it spawns, such as OpenSSH, from prompting.  There is no way to do that.

Thus, if you're looking to clone from most major hosting sites, you'll be better off using HTTPS URLs because in that case OpenSSH isn't used and all authentication prompts are handled by Git.  In such a case, if authentication is required, it will simply fail.

Note that preventing terminal prompts doesn't prevent other credential managers from opening windows or such.  You'd need to clear all credential helpers by invoking Git like `git -c credential.helper= clone` and make sure both the `GIT_ASKPASS` and `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variables are unset.

Comment: this one is nice. though there are few things I experienced, you may edit your answer to reflect them. git will still popup credential window if a windows manager (i.e usual windows desktop) is running, and it will internally redirect to HTTPS even when you give HTTP link.

Comment: I've provided a solution for the credential windows popping up.  Git doesn't automatically redirect to HTTPS, but the site in question may do so.  All major hosting sites use HTTPS only and always redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: you have just made your answer greater ;) using empty helper improves greatly. now I am much more confident to improve my script